# ArrayController pushObject reference.type error

Tags: ember.js

EDIT: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uniyel/2/edit) of problem. See comments in the testAddTom action method of IndexController.

I have a controller that adds a model object to another ArrayController in my app. However when I call pushObject on the ArrayController an error is thrown...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_create' of undefined ember-data-latest.js:2769
>   DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.materializeRecord
>   ember-data-latest.js:2769
>   DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.recordForReference
>   ember-data-latest.js:1871
>   DS.RecordArray.Ember.ArrayProxy.extend.objectAtContent
>   ember-data-latest.js:309 superWrapper ember.js:1044
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.objectAt ember.js:11475
>   superWrapper ember.js:1044
>   Ember.ArrayController.Ember.ArrayProxy.extend.objectAtContent
>   ember.js:13111 superWrapper ember.js:1044
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.objectAt ember.js:11475
>   superWrapper ember.js:1044
>   Ember.Array.Ember.Mixin.create.arrayContentDidChange ember.js:8955
>   Ember.ArrayController.Ember.ArrayProxy.extend.arrayContentDidChange
>   ember.js:13147 superWrapper ember.js:1044
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.arrangedContentArrayDidChange
>   ember.js:11582 sendEvent ember.js:2432
>   Ember.Array.Ember.Mixin.create.arrayContentDidChange ember.js:8946
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.arrangedContentArrayDidChange
>   ember.js:11582 sendEvent ember.js:2432
>   Ember.Array.Ember.Mixin.create.arrayContentDidChange ember.js:8946
>   Ember.Mixin.create.replace ember.js:12016
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.replaceContent ember.js:11371
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend._replace ember.js:11487
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.replace ember.js:11493
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.replaceContent ember.js:11371
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend._replace ember.js:11487
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend._insertAt ember.js:11501
>   Ember.ArrayProxy.Ember.Object.extend.pushObject

The model object isn't new, it's already fetched earlier on. If I instead get the ArrayController content, convert it to an array, push the object to the array and then re-set the ArrayController.content it works okay.

My question is why isn't pushObject working? It seems the right thing to do.

pushObject code sample which breaks...

```
App.TaskController.reopen({
    needs: ['reminder'],

    showReminderForTask: function(reminder) {
        var reminders = this.get('controllers.reminders');

        if (!reminders.content.contains(reminder)) {
            reminders.pushObject(reminder);
        }
    }
});
```

ArrayController.content example which works....

```
App.TaskController.reopen({
    needs: ['reminder'],

    showReminderForTask: function(reminder) {
        var reminders = this.get('controllers.reminders');

        if (!reminders.content.contains(reminder)) {
            var content = reminders.content.toArray();
            content.push(reminder);
            reminders.set('content', content);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you are trying to use `pushObject` on the controller itself which does not automatically forwards the pushed objects to the `content` property of the controller, and therefore it breaks.

You should rather do this:

```
App.TaskController.reopen({
  needs: ['reminder'],

  showReminderForTask: function(reminder) {
    var remindersContent = this.get('controllers.reminders.content');

    if (!remindersContent.contains(reminder)) {
        remindersContent.pushObject(reminder);
    }
  }
});
```

I've put together a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/elavez/4/edit) that show that using `pushObject` on the `content` property should work as expected.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer intuitivepixel. Your example works perfectly but when working with models the same error is thrown on pushObject. Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uniyel/2/edit) of what I mean.

Maybe it's a bug with ember-data?